# Como hacer que se deslice un layout oculto en mi aplicacion con un gesto

Tags: android, android-layout

LLevo poco tiempo aprendiendo **android** y quisiera implementar esa funcionalidad, adjunto un ejemplo:

la pantalla inicial es la de la derecha y al tocar la barra color cyan me desplaza el submenu, tapando cierta superficie de la vista anterior.

Quisiera saber si me podrían dar ideas de como hacerlo, no se si hacerlo con actividades o fragmentos o como hacer ese efecto de desplazamiento, Muchas gracias.

[image: Imagen de como se ve el menu desplazado]

Comment: Hola!, haz investigado sobre el OnTouchListener y sus tipos de eventos?

Comment: coméntanos lo que has intentado :D

Comment: Prueba con NavigationView http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35464425/navigationview-on-both-side

Comment: hola :) , si claro, lo uso para reconocer el swipe, ya he logrado lanzar animaciones con el swipe, pero no es igual al de la calculadora de google en la que a medida en que muevo mi dedo se va mostrando el menú y oscurece lo que esta atras, lo he intentado con viewPager usando fragmentos pero no me superpone el menu solo navego entre los fragmentos. Probare lo de navigation View a ver que sale, gracias.